Oracle SQL UPDATE Statement, Needs to Begin with SELECT
I have my update script:
UPDATE SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
SET FLAG = 2
WHERE ID = 'UNIQUE_001'

What I need to do now, is try and get that query to run, with a SELECT statement at the beginning. SELECT needs to be the first six characters of my query.
When trying:
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
UPDATE SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
SET FLAG = 2
WHERE ID = 'UNIQUE_001'

dBeaver runs the SELECT * FROM DUAL; part but then a red triangle appears at the beginning of line 2 (the UPDATE) with the error code:

SQL Error [936] [42000]: ORA-00936: missing expression

When trying:
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
UPDATE SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
SET FLAG = 2
WHERE ID = 'UNIQUE_001';

With a second ; at the end of the second statement, I get a red triangle on the DUAL line saying:

SQL Error [933] [42000]: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Has anyone got any other suggestions?

You code works fiddle. If you have an SQL script containing multiple statements make sure that there is a statement terminator (either ; or \ for SQL statements and just \ for PL/SQL statements) after each statement. Beyond that, you will need to [edit] the question and provide a [MRE] with a way to replicate the issue (including details of which language/application/tool is generating that error).

Thanks @MT0, I have updated my question with the SQL Error [936] [42000]: ORA-00936: missing expression error.

Do you have anything after the UPDATE statement? You do not show a ; after the WHERE clause of the UPDATE and if there are more statements then it is likely that DBeaver thinks the two statements are one and is sending them to the database together which is causing a syntax error. The solution would be to put ; after each SQL statement. I can't quite get the same error but fiddle is close.

Interesting @MT0, if I add the ; to the end of the second statement, my error changes to 933, 42000: SQL command no properly ended.  Updating question...

Your statements should work ... you can try any of: (a) Using \ (on a new line) instead of ; as the statement terminator; (b) putting a blank line between statements; or (c) deleting everything and re-typing it (in case there are invisible characters). Neither (a) and (b) should make any difference and I think (c) is unlikely.

"SELECT needs to be the first six characters of my query" - why? Are you trying to work around a specific limitation/requirement in your client? What do you expect to happen to the results from that query? It sounds like you're trying to trick some mechanism that only supports query to run an update statement instead.

In dBeaver you should click on "Execute Script" - If you click the "Play" button then you get that error.
Alternatively: Select all commands in the script (blue when selected) and press ALT+X.
